# Generating Synthetic Food Orders

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-models

I have some transactional data for users who have ordered food. However, I am not allowed to share this data but am allowed to augment or generate a synthetic sample and share it. I was thinking about using generative adversarial networks for this purpose.

```
Data might look like:
t_0 = ['burger', 'fries', 'coke'] 
t_1 = ['chicken sandwich', 'sweet potato tots'] 
t_2 = ['buffalo chicken sandwich', 'caesar salad', 'iced tea', 'nachos', 'cheese burger', 'fries'] 
.
.
.
```

These orders could all have different dimension as some transactions have ordered more food than others. I know that I can create k-hot vectors of these items and pad the vectors such that they all have the same dimension and feed this as the input into the GAN. There is potentially 1,000 distinct items, so I am wondering that this k-hot feature vector will be too large.I was wondering if there was a more sound way of either using GANs for this purpose or an alternate generative model with feature ideas which might accomplish the goal of generating these synthetic orders.

Answer (score 0):

A very natural choice for this type of problems is the application of [Apriori Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) that calculates the association rules. Alternatively, [Bayesian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) can be used. Both of them are well documented and implemented in both Python and R.

In your case, Bayesian network may work better as you can easily sample from it because it represents a random distribution. A starting point may be [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol0l6aTfb_g), but there may be better material on that.

Similarly, you can use [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://fastml.com/dimensionality-reduction-for-sparse-binary-data/) which is primarily dedicated to text mining where each sample is considered as a bag of words. In your case, you play with bag of items which is from the perspective of LDA the very same.

Regarding GAN, it may be possible to use [RNN GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09444) where it may be possible to sample a sequence of the items but I am not very sure about this approach.

Comment: Thanks @Karel that is very helpful. I have used LDA for the purpose of topic modeling on data such as movie titles/reviews. Can you elaborate a little more on that, I am not fully following how I would use bag of words to generate this random sample. Once I have the words from the order data all bagged up, what is the next best step to get the random orders? Thank you for pointing me to the Apriori Algorithm. I am looking into this and the Bayesian network but am interested in LDA for this, I did not think of that.